# Passing  variable to jQuery ui Dialog box 

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i need to pass a variable called 'test_var' to my dialog box 
but i don't know how to do that

how can i pass variable from my function that calls the dialog box to dialog box ?

```
    //a tag calls to starter function and sends variable as parameter

        <a href="#" onclick="starter(test_var)"> go </a>
    //starter func recives the test_var and calls the dialog box 
//what i want is to somehow send test_var to dialogbox in here


            function starter(test_var){

           //some stuff 

            $('#dialog_div').dialog('open');
            return false;
            }
            }


            $('#dialog_div').dialog({
            aoutoOpen:false,
            with:600,
            buttons:{
            "ok":function(){

    // i want to be able to alert test_var in here 
            alert(test_var)
            }
            }
            })

        }
```

i've tried

```
function starter(test_var){

       //some stuff 

        $('#dialog_div').dialog('open' , test_Val);
        return false;
        }
and

$('#dialog_div').dialog(test_val , {//coode
})
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you want to *do* with the variable?

Comment: i want to send it to another page by ajax but firs i need user comment and confirmation thats why i need a dialog box

Comment: Do you need to use the variable as part of the display in the dialog box? Where's the variable coming from?

Comment: no i just want to send it to another page , it's a parameter from my first function (starter())

Comment: Then you don't need to pass it to the dialog box, just use it in your ajax call.

Comment: thing is ajax call will be made when user presses ok button from dialog box , in the example code i've put alert(test_val) instead of ajax call to keep it simple

Comment: If the variable exists you don't need to pass it anywhere; JavaScript has only two scopes, global, and function. Without knowing what's actually happening, it's difficult to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Just make it a top level variable and then the dialog will have direct access to it.